# MySQL Joining Four Tables with Foreign Key SELECT Statement Rejecting Third

Tags: mysql, join

Not sure if I'm entirely doing this correctly, as it's my first go-around with foreign keys.

I'm trying to do a `JOIN` on four tables.

- inventory_detail_history
- shipments

along with these two which hold the foreign key

- shipment_details (wholesale)
- shipment_ids

I've applied a foreign key constraint on `shipment_details` `id` field.
This references a `shipment_id` column on my `shipment_ids` table.

`shipment_details` has the following columns: `id`, `QuantityPurchased`, `UnitCost`, `FreightTotal`, `CustomDutiesTotal`

`shipment_ids` has the following columns:
`id`, `SKU`, `shipment_id`

The idea is an attempt to normalize my database by applying multiple SKUs to a particular `shipment_id` (or, I guess, rather, the `shipment_details` `id`).

Doing an `INNER JOIN` on the two tables `inventory_detail_history` and `shipments` was no problem:

```
SELECT Shipments.ListingSKU, Shipments.SKU, idh.Quantity, Shipments.OrderIdentifier, idh.Price, Shipments.SalesTax, Shipments.ShippingCharge, Shipments.ShipmentCost, idh.FinalValueFee, idh.PayPalFee
FROM Inventory_detail_history AS idh
INNER JOIN Shipments ON idh.OrderIdentifier = Shipments.OrderIdentifier
WHERE Shipments.SKU = 'SKU-NAME';
```

This produces an output like this:

[image]

But now I need to join this with my `shipment_details` table which references the `SKU` from the `shipment_details.id` and `shipment_ids.shipment_id` relationship.

I can do this seperately.

```
SELECT sd.PurchaseQuantity, sd.UnitCost, sd.FreightTotal, sd.CustomDutiesTotal, sids.SKU, sids.shipment_id
FROM shipment_details AS sd
INNER JOIN shipment_ids AS sids on sd.id = sids.shipment_id
WHERE sids.SKU = 'SKU-NAME';
```

which produces an output like so:

[image]

But, I need to put all this information on one row.

Here's my best shot so far.

```
SELECT Shipments.ListingSKU, Shipments.SKU, idh.Quantity, Shipments.OrderIdentifier, idh.Price, Shipments.SalesTax, Shipments.ShippingCharge, Shipments.ShipmentCost, idh.FinalValueFee, idh.PayPalFee, sd.PurchaseQuantity, sd.UnitCost, sd.FreightTotal, sd.CustomDutiesTotal, sids.SKU, sids.shipment_id
FROM Inventory_detail_history AS idh
INNER JOIN Shipments 
ON idh.OrderIdentifier = Shipments.OrderIdentifier
WHERE Shipments.SKU = 'SKU-NAME'
INNER JOIN shipment_ids AS sids
ON sids.SKU = 'SKU-NAME'
INNER JOIN shipment_details AS sd
ON sd.id = sids.shipment_id
```

But I'm getting an error

> > #1054 - Unknown column 'sd.PurchaseQuantity' in 'field list'

Note that this column is irrelevant, it's just rejecting the third table select.
If I change it to `SELECT . . . . idh.PayPalFee, sd.UnitCost, sd.PurchaseQuantity`

It'll say `#1054 - Unknown column 'sd.UnitCost' in 'field list'`

Any help, tips someone can provide to get an appropriate response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the where clause at the end of the query, instead of after the second join should resolve the error.

Comment: You're correct, lol. I was close, so that's good. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please mark the answer as correct :)